# using 'this' in an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, this

I have an if statment that's not working correctly and I believe it's because of the use of 'this' but I'm not sure how to fix it.  This is the code:

```
$('.enlarge').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).find(".enlarged_txt").attr('id');
    $('#full_image').animate({
        height: "100%"
    }, 300, function() {

    if ( $(this).hasClass("v") ) {   
        $('#full_image img').attr('src','http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/instruments/violins/full/' + id + '.jpg');
        fadeIn($('#full_image img'));
        $("#close_2").css({
            display: "block"
        });
        $("#close").css({
            display: "block"
        });            
    }

    });
});




        <div class="enlarge v" style="float:right;margin-right:70px;margin-top:5px;">
            <img class="enlarged_unselected" style="float:left;margin-top:6px;" src="http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/elements/fullscreen_unselected.png"/>
            <img class="enlarged_selected" style="float:left;display:none;" src="http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/elements/fullscreen_selected.png"/>
            <div id="ChasHunnicutt_1928" style="float:left;padding-left:8px;" class="enlarged_txt">Enlarge Image</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Its not beacuse of if.You have written it correctly.there is some other issue in your code.

Comment: try assigning $(this) to a variable and use that variable afterwards.

Comment: does this work: var id = $(this).find(".enlarged_txt").attr('id')? I would have thought $(this).find(".enlarged_txt") would return an array

Comment: try `$(e.currentTarget).hasClass` and add `e` to the function like `function(e)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a problem with `this` in this.
Because the second time you use `this` you use it in a new function inside the `animate(` call. This time you use `this` the `this` references ([according to this jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)) the "DOM element being animated."

If you want to reference the original `this` passed in by the .`click(` handler to your top level function (which references the DOM element being clicked) you need to save it first, then replace the second `this` with that saved reference to the original `this`. 
**Keywords are fun.**

Like so :

```
$('.enlarge').click(function() {
    var jthis = this; // save the reference to the $('.enlarge') that was clicked
    var id = $(this).find(".enlarged_txt").attr('id');
    $('#full_image').animate({
        height: "100%"
    }, 300, function() {

    if ( $(jthis).hasClass("v") ) {   
        $('#full_image img').attr('src','http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/instruments/violins/full/' + id + '.jpg');
        fadeIn($('#full_image img'));
        $("#close_2").css({
            display: "block"
        });
        $("#close").css({
            display: "block"
        });            
    }
    });
});
```

Which should fix the problem with `this`.

Comment: You are very welcome @loriensleafs! Would you mind accepting my answer if it works for you and is not too much trouble?